# ModelMapper error-org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: force initializing collection loading: Spring Boot and JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, arraylist, hashset, modelmapper

I am working on a Spring Boot Project. I have 3 entities-

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Author {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Author_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="First_name",nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="Last_name",nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="Mobile_number",nullable = false, unique = true,length = 10)
    private long mobileNo;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    // List<Book> books=new ArrayList<>();
    private Set<Book> books=new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
package com.ayushsingh.demojpa.entity;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Book_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "Book_name",nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String bookName;

    @Column(name = "Publication_date",nullable = false)
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date publishDate;

    @Column(name = "ISBN",nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String isbn;

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name = "publication_id", nullable = false)
    private Publication publication;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Book_Author", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "Book_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "Author_id"))
    // private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();
    private Set<Author> authors=new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
package com.ayushsingh.demojpa.entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class Publication {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="Publication_name",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="Registration_number",nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String regNumber;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "publication",cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.DETACH})
    // List<Book> books=new ArrayList<>();
    private Set<Book> books=new HashSet<>();
}
```

DTO Classes-

```
package com.ayushsingh.demojpa.dto;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class BookDto {

    private int id;

    private String bookName;

    private Date publishDate;

    private String isbn;

  
    private PublicationDto publication;

   
    // private List<AuthorDto> authors = new ArrayList<>();
        private Set<AuthorDto> authors=new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
package com.ayushsingh.demojpa.dto;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class AuthorDto {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private long mobileNo;
    // List<BookDto> books=new ArrayList<>();
    // Set<BookDto> books=new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
package com.ayushsingh.demojpa.dto;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


import com.ayushsingh.demojpa.entity.Book;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class PublicationDto {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    private String regNumber;
    // List<BookDto> books=new ArrayList<>();
    // HashSet<BookDto> books=new HashSet<>();
}
```

When using Model Mapper, I get error when converting the entities to dtos. But, with List everything works fine.

```
023-05-20T19:28:57.369+05:30 ERROR 8632 --- [nio-8086-exec-6] org.hibernate.AssertionFailure           : HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: force initializing collection loading   
2023-05-20T19:28:57.388+05:30 ERROR 8632 --- [nio-8086-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: force initializing collection loading] with root cause  

org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: force initializing collection loading
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:811) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:1003) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:989) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
```

Please help me resolve this error. Please note- When using List/ArrayList, everything works fine with the same code. Problem arises with HashSet.

Comment: place `@lombok.EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` over set fields, or replace `@Data` with `@Getter` and `@Setter` an implement reliable `#equals` and `#hashCode` methods.

Comment: Placing lombok.EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude worked for me. Can somebody explain why this issue occurs and how lombok.EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude works here? Thank You.